# How to run the imported Spring mvc project in Intellij?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ and imported the Spring MVC project.I configured the maven setup and used `mvn clean install`  to build my project.And for running I configured tomcat:run on the configuration of IntelliJ. But red markers are shown as:

[image]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.luv2code</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>spring-security-demo</name>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>5.0.2.RELEASE</springframework.version>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring MVC support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet, JSP and JSTL support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <!-- TO DO: Add support for Maven WAR Plugin -->
    <build>
        <finalName>spring-security-demo</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
             <plugins>
                 <plugin>
                     <!-- Add maven coordinate for maven war plugin-->
                     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin -->

                         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                         <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                         <version>3.2.3</version>


                 </plugin>
             </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

But it is successfully compiling and while running consoles printed are:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe"
>   -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\AshwinPC\Desktop\Spring-Security\spring-security-demo-starter\spring-security-demo-01-base-app
>   "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community
>   Edition 2019.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3"
>   "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community
>   Edition 2019.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf"
>   "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
>   Community Edition 2019.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar"
>   "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
>   2019.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=61598:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath
>   "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
>   2019.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2019.2 tomcat:run
>   [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]  [INFO] -----------------<
>   com.luv2code:spring-security-demo >------------------ [INFO] Building
>   spring-security-demo 1.0 [INFO] --------------------------------[ war
>   ]--------------------------------- [INFO]  [INFO] >>>
>   tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) > compile @
>   spring-security-demo >>> [INFO]  [INFO] ---
>   maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @
>   spring-security-demo --- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8
>   actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform
>   dependent! [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory
>   C:\Users\AshwinPC\Desktop\Spring-Security\spring-security-demo-starter\spring-security-demo-01-base-app\src\main\resources
>   [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile)
>   @ spring-security-demo --- [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are
>   up to date [INFO]  [INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run
>   (default-cli) < compile @ spring-security-demo <<< [INFO]  [INFO] 
>   [INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @
>   spring-security-demo --- [INFO] Running war on
>   http://localhost:8080/spring-security-demo [INFO] Creating Tomcat
>   server configuration at
>   C:\Users\AshwinPC\Desktop\Spring-Security\spring-security-demo-starter\spring-security-demo-01-base-app\target\tomcat
>   Aug 09, 2019 10:49:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start
>   INFO: Starting tomcat server Aug 09, 2019 10:49:23 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start INFO: Starting Servlet
>   Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29 Aug 09, 2019 10:49:24 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init INFO: Initializing Coyote
>   HTTP/1.1 on http-8080 Aug 09, 2019 10:49:24 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start INFO: Starting Coyote
>   HTTP/1.1 on http-8080

And when I hit :`http://localhost:8080/spring-security-demo/`

[image]

Other configuration classes are:

DemoController.java

```
  package com.luv2code.springsecurity.demo.controller;


    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

    @Controller
    public class DemoController {

        @GetMapping("/")
        public String showHome(){
            return "home";
        }


    }
```

Config class:

```
package com.luv2code.springsecurity.demo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.luv2code")
public class DemoAppConfig {

    //bean for viewresolver
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver=new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }




}
```

Dispatcher Servlet config

```
package com.luv2code.springsecurity.demo.config;


import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MySpringMVcDispatcherServletInitilizer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses(){
         return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses(){
          return  new Class[] {DemoAppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected  String[] getServletMappings(){
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }


}
```

Comment: In the controller, modify the getmapping like this @GetMapping("") and try

Comment: no cnanges in output

Comment: Can you try something like @Getmapping("home") and ping the URL http://localhost:8080/spring-security-demo/home and try?

Comment: If that does not work, remove in the servlet config, use empty string instead of "/" in getServletMappings method

Comment: no its not running

Comment: Can you please go to the target folder and say the name of the war file present there?

Comment: spring-security-demo.war

Comment: Change the servlet-api version to 2.5 and try?

Comment: Do `Click on RUN tab -> Edit Configurations -> Select Tomcate server -> Select Deployment tab -> In Application Context put only /`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do something like this:
*File->Project Structure->Modules-> **Check whether Web module been added***
*If 'no':*
 1. Add this module. Then see point 2.
*If 'yes':*
Check *Web Resource Directories* there:
 2. It must point to your path to **webapp** directory.

Answer (score 0):

In your DemoController  showHome should return a ModelAndView 
something like this then ViewResolver will map it to `home.jsp`

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView showHome() {
    return new ModelAndView("home");
}
```

You can also refer [here](https://www.viralpatel.net/spring-3-mvc-create-hello-world-application-spring-3-mvc/) for more detail

Comment: the red marks are shown saying dependecny not found. please see the pic i uploaded

Comment: You want to resolve 1. red mark issue or 2. when you hit http://localhost:8080/spring-security-demo/ you are not able to see your jsp.  As per console log your application is up and running.

Comment: when i hit the URL i am not seeing the jsp. and why is the red marker showing.. it is not showing in eclipse but shows on intellij